# How do I setup a Cron Quartz Trigger on Startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, spring-boot-starter

I am setting up a few CronTriggers to kickoff a few different batch jobs at different times.

I have tried to search online, but can only find answers on how to schedule after say a web call or inside a different service class. I want theses triggers to be scheduled on startup.

How can I do that?

I have already built the Triggers and the JobDetails via their respective builders.

I am using Spring-boot-starter-quartz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is to create a class that implements ApplicationRunner or CommandLineRunner. On startup of a spring application, spring will execute run command in this class and you can programmatically call your task on startup.

See this if you want more info:

https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-commandlinerunner-and-applicationrunner-example

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this. I just now double checked my code, my problem wasn't the wiring. It was the fact that I was returning null on my triggers because they weren't built.

Comment: Turns out I did not call the function afterPropertiesSet().

And, turns out that I didn't need to use CommandLineRunner at all because Spring-boot-starter-quartz seems to schedule them automatically.

... RIP ME